# Python matplotlib / connecting plots with line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a tool that opens a stream to Twitter's API and analyzes tweets based on their sentiment. The logic for this is stored inside a class. I'm using global variables to store the values generated by the class (all integers). They are continuously updated as tweets are processed.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from textblob import TextBlob
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re, json, time, datetime
import numpy as np
import tweepy

count = 0 
class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
    ....(logic for processing data)....

    global count
    count = count + 1
```

I'm using matplotlib to plot the aggregated values every X second. To accomplish this I am:

1. using a while loop outside my subclass to call the global variables
2. plot values in globals to a chart
3. reset globals to their original value (0)
4. repeat every X second

My solution for plotting aggregated data every X second to a chart:

```
plt.ion() # for an interactive chart
read_frequency = 5 # how frequent we plot values to chart (seconds)

while True:

    time.sleep(read_frequency)
    now = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

    # prints aggregated data to terminal
    print(f'{now} Total: {count}')

    x = now
    y = count

    plt.plot(x, y, color = 'black', marker = 'o')

    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.0001)

    # Reset aggregate data in global variables
    count = 0
```

The issue I have now is that since I reset the globals, my ydata, there is no relation between the plots. So instead of a linestyle chart, I get a chart with individual plots.

[My current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgxGr.png)

How I can force a relationship between the plots for the purpose of drawing a line between them?

Comment: Try search this site with `[matplotlib] line between subplots`.

Comment: The code you show would plot only `0`s. So there must be something which you don't show here. In any case, don't use the graphics to store the values, instead store them in lists. Then update the plot will the lists' data. For further help on this you would need to update the code in the question with how you get `y` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data from the figure itself if you do not keep the aggregated data. So you can get the last (x,y) plotted line with

```
line = plt.gca().get_lines()[-1]
xd = line.get_xdata()
yd = line.get_ydata()
```

And then plot a new line using the last value from `xd` and `yd`, and your new values

```
x0, y0 = xd[-1], yd[-1]
plt.plot([x0, x], [y0, y], color = 'black', marker = 'o')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try out your suggestion and I'm not getting a line drawn between the plots, it places another plot on top of my original plot. 

If I do the following, however, it draws a **horizontal** line from the x position of the first plot to the y position of the new plot:

`plt.plot([x0, x], color = 'black', marker = 'o')`

I'm tinkering around with your solution and can't seem to make it draw between the plots.

Comment: If you could provide a minimal working example it would be easier. But I can't do much without this

Comment: Also add an exception for the first plot to draw in the loop, since you cannot get any lines from previous plots.